# Identify insect

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

I am from north east India and I found a really beautiful bug in my backyard.
Can someone please help me identifying it?

Size: about 3 cm long and 1.5 cm wide.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't say what species this beetle is but I think it's a species in the *Anomala* genus in the subfamily *Rutelinae* (Shining Leaf Chafers). One photo I can link you to is found at Coleoptera Atlas [Anomala grandis](http://www.coleoptera-atlas.com/cetoniidae-scarabaeoidea/rutelinae/Anomalini/Anomala-Anomalina/Anomala-grandis).

Dorsal view of *Anomala grandis*
[image]

Ventral view of *Anomala grandis*
[image]

The only reason I wouldn't consider it specifically to be the beetle you found is because the beetle in the photo occurs in Thailand. How far it range is, I have no idea. It might be found as far as you are. A common name for it is little green leaf beetle. Coleoptera Atlas lists its maximum size at 27 mm. There is another larger *Anomala* species that looks similar called *Anomala cupripes* or large green chafer beetle. I wonder about the reliability of some of the sources though as it's only supposed to be 20 mm! The name is also one used around 1900 so it might even be the same as *A. grandis*.

If the photos look like they fit your beetle, and depending on the size of yours, you can use this information to make some inquiries in your region. It's all I can do as resources in English about insects in other parts of the world are often limited.

Comment: I think the hair is missing from the photo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a *Chrysina Lecontei*, a type of scarab. Perhaps you can provide a better top and bottom photo (directly above and below)?

Comment: Sorry but it was dead when i found it,and i dont get the chance to take more photos.

Comment: This _is_ a scarab, but the species given in the answer is from the wrong side of the planet (see http://bugguide.net/node/view/134203/bgimage for images with locality data); Google-searching "Scarabaeidae India" results in more than 100,000 hits; fortunately a starting point (the _Fauna of British India_  series) does have a partial online presence (see here: http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/36758#page/5/mode/1up) but is also quite old: the first part of the three available dates from 1910 ...

Comment: Please remember that the Latin name of the species starts with lower case (C. lecontei).